# Saving XML In Correct Format Using PHP And DOM

Tags: php, xml, dom, xml-parsing

i am facing a problem in updating my XML using PHP & DOM.My XML file is in this format:

**Original XML (& desired xml layout):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<Rows>
  <Row CustomerAccountNumber="COU002" />
  <Row CustomerAccountNumber="COU023" />
  <Row CustomerAccountNumber="C2335" />
  <Row CustomerAccountNumber="CvbU002" />
```

And the code that saves i.e adds the new record to the XML(customer.xml) is:

```
<?php

$xmldoc=new DOMDocument();
$xmldoc->load('XML/customer.xml');

$newAct= 'c12345';

$root = $xmldoc->firstChild;

$newElement= $xmldoc->createElement('CustomerAccountNumber');
$root->appendChild($newElement);
$newText= $xmldoc->createTextNode($newAct);
$newElement->appendChild($newText);

$xmldoc->save('XML/customer.xml');
 ?>
```

**Issue :** The Code is generating the new record in this format:

```
  <Rows>
  <Row CustomerAccountNumber="COU002" />
  <Row CustomerAccountNumber="COU023" />
  <Row CustomerAccountNumber="C2335" />
  <Row CustomerAccountNumber="CvbU002" />
  <CustomerAccountNumber>c12345</CustomerAccountNumber>

</Rows>
```

I couldn't understand where i am making mistake.All i want to retain my original XML format.I want output file in the above mentioned original format(See top).Kindly guide me and point me where i am making mistake that is generating incorrect format within the file itself.Plz help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you are currently creating a new `CustomerAccountNumber` *element*.  Instead, you want to create a new `Row` element, and then [create a new `CustomerAccountNumber` attribute](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createattribute.php):

```
$newElement = $xmldoc->createElement('Row');
$newAttribute = $xmldoc->createAttribute('CustomerAccountNumber');
$newAttribute->value = $newAct;
$newElement->appendChild($newAttribute);
$root->appendChild($newElement);
```